# Connect to external mongo database (java)

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection, mlab

I'm trying to connect to my mongo database which I created via mongolab

There's standard uri mentioned at my database's page at mongolab:[image]

I try this code:

```
String uriString = "mongodb://user:password@ds047037.mongolab.com:47037/db_test_01";
MongoURI uri = new MongoURI(uriString);
try {
    DB db = uri.connectDB();
    db.authenticate(uri.getUsername(), uri.getPassword());
    Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();
    for (String s : colls) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("done");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + e);
    } catch(MongoException me) {
        System.out.println("MongoException: " + me);
    }
```

However, I get `UnknownHostException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ds047037.mongolab.com`

Docs about `UnknownHostException` say: "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the error? It may help in pinpointing the exact cause. You can use [`java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) to get the full trace to go to stderr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a DNS resolution problem at some point in the stack. [`java.net.UnknownHostException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) is "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined".

**Problem with Java**

The problem may be with Java itself. There is a [known issue with Java and IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608503/domain-name-resolution-not-working-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu64-9-04-machine). You can try setting the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` system property to `true` to see if that fixes the issue.

As a parameter to the `java` command when launching your JVM:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true YourMainClass
```

Or programmatically:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

You can also try upgrading to the latest version of Java to get all the bug fixes that come with it.

**Problem with your DNS server or configuration**

The issue may also be with the DNS configuration on your laptop/machine. You can use `dig` to see what that DNS lookup returns. Below is the output of what I get from my laptop. You can also use [this web version of dig](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=ds047037.mongolab.com&type=&showcommand=on&colorize=on&stats=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) to see what you should be getting.

```
% dig ds047037.mongolab.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ds047037.mongolab.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20375
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ds047037.mongolab.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ds047037.mongolab.com.  120 IN  CNAME   ds047037-a.mongolab.com.
ds047037-a.mongolab.com. 120    IN  CNAME   h000432.mongolab.com.
h000432.mongolab.com.   120 IN  CNAME   ec2-46-51-159-130.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-46-51-159-130.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. 300 IN A 46.51.159.130

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 12 13:22:24 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 162
```

If you confirm that your DNS configuration / server is the issue, you will need to [determine which DNS servers you're using](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-what-my-dns-servers-address-is/) and then contact the owner / administrator or contact your ISP to make sure they're configured as they should be.

Comment: I used dig and got an answer almost equal as yours. It means that it's ok with DNS?

Comment: Did you run dig from the machine that ran the Java you posted or from the web site I linked?

Comment: It's also possible you're running into the [known bug with the Java IPv6 stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608503/domain-name-resolution-not-working-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu64-9-04-machine), causing DNS resolution to fail from inside Java only. Try adding the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` Java option.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **host** and **port**, so:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("ds047037.mongolab.com", 47037);
DB db = mongo.getDB("db_test_01");
db.authenticate(user, password);
```

Comment: Yes, they're correct. From docs about UnknownHostException: "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.". Why ip-adr couldn't be determined??

Comment: You have a firewall which is blocking the outbound request?

Comment: Try to connect with the commandline tool to check if that works