# A strange UnknownHostException

Tags: java, dns, ipv6

In a web project .
I see the log:

```
hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKConfig - java.net.UnknownHostException: example.com 
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1201)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1154)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:970)
```

but when I **ping example.com**, it's ok, I also **telnet example.com 2181** successfully!
I found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608503/domain-name-resolution-not-working-in-java-applications-on-ubuntu64-9-04-machine)
so I run the DomainResolutionTest in my Server  **java DomainResolutionTest example.com**

but it's ok !

env:

```
java -version
```

java version "1.6.0_25" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

`os:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7`

**I am curious why is Inet6AddressImpl,I think it  may be Inet4AddressImpl**

How to solve it? 

What's the cause ?

Comment: Is it repeatable? It was probably just a temporary DNS failure.

Comment: if you have problem with ipv6, you could specify some jvm flag to force use ipv4 only.

Comment: @RobinGreen ,it is repeatable.every times it appears.

Comment: I find the answer.because i make a mistabke ,the config hostname contains black .Thanks all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have had the same exception and solved it by setting my hostname manually in /etc/hosts for the 'localhost' entry both.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost DL006285-linux

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback DL006285-linux
```

Answer (score 8):

If it is a dual stack (ipv6 + v4) Java prefers ipv6.

You can force it to prefer ipv4, if your ipv6 is misconfigured somehow.

Set system property with: 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

soure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/

Comment: this is exactly what happened when I use aws jdk on EC2.... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There may be problem in giving the subnet value to the program.
I gave the subnet value by trimming it before passing to the program.

```
subnet = subnet.trim();
int timeout = 1500;
for(int i=1;i<254;i++)
        {
        try
          {
            String host = subnet +"."+i;
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout))
              {
                Check = Check+host+"\n";
                System.out.println(host);
              } 

           }
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) { 
            Logger.getLogger(WiFi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WiFi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```