# Unknown Host Exception on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-3.2

I've been experiencing this kind of error upon running my test script on JMeter?

java.net.UnknownHostException: h2ebiz-testat java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056979/a-strange-unknownhostexception/28880302#28880302

Answer (score 0):

`h2ebiz-testat` doesn't look like a normal Internet address to me, if you can access this host via web browser but getting the [UnknownHostException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) in JMeter most probably you don't have a direct network connection on your machine and you're accessing Intranet and Internet resources via proxy server.

So check your [browser proxy settings](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows) and make sure to [configure JMeter to use your company proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server), it can be done in 2 ways:

1. Using [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port .....
   ```

   in this case you will need to pass these arguments each time you start JMeter
2. Using [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), add the next lines:

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=your_proxy_host
   https.ProxyPort=your_proxy_port
   https.proxyPort=your_proxy_port
   ```

   in this case the changes will be permanent